# Accessing the index of an object displayed with v-if on click

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-sfc

I have an object that i am displaying dynamically on the screen with nested v-if statements. This object is displayed as a table.
I want each "cell" to have a click handler that returns the indices of that exact "cell" so that i can assign a value on click.

This is my object:

```
const table = {
  header: ['Name', 'Runter', 'Frei', 'Hoch', 'Neiba'],
  one: { name: '1', runter: '', frei: '', hoch: '', neiba: '' },
  two: { name: '2', runter: '', frei: '', hoch: '', neiba: '' },
  three: { name: '3', runter: '', frei: '', hoch: '', neiba: '' },
};
```

This is my html code:

```
<table>
  <tr v-for="(key, object) in table" :key="object">
    <td v-for="value in key" :key="value" @click="logIt(key)">
      {{ value }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

logIt is just a simple function to console.log the current cell:

```
function logIt(cell) {
  console.log(cell);
}
```

With the current configuration this is the output in chrome dev tools when i click on a cell in the row starting with 2:

```
{name: '2', runter: '', frei: '', hoch: '', neiba: ''}
```

I am trying to achieve a output like this so i can assign a value to that variable:

```
two.runter
```

If it helps here is a screenshot of the displayed table:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-for` on objects returns the object `key` and `value` 'backwards'. This means that you probably want to reverse the variable names used in your code:

```
<table>
  <tr v-for="(data, key) in table" :key="key">
    <!-- key = one; data = { name: '1', runter: '', frei: '', hoch: '', neiba: '' } -->
    <td v-for="(value, subkey) in data" :key="subkey" @click="logIt(key)">
      <!-- subkey = name; value = '1' -->
      {{ value }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Depending on which parameters you want, you can pass multiple parameters to `logIt` - e.g. `@click=logIt(key, value)`

Bear in mind that since the value of the first item in `data` - `headers` - is a list, you will need to take extra steps to handle this differently, probably as a `thead` row.